# Spring boot app fails to connect to Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, spring-jms

A simple SpringBoot based console app is unable to connect to a local Weblogic JMS server. I am getting the following error:

`access denied ("javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission", "register")`

After amending the `java.policy` file with the relevant configuration, the error disappears. But, I would like to know why we need this explicit permission enabling is required. I am invoking the `jar` as myself using `java -jar` method.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I had to disable Spring JMX setup. And that solved the issue.